# Using Spring Websocket without STOMP client

Tags: java, spring-webflux, stomp, spring-websocket

I am working on a brownfield project.
It is a websocket server that allows clients to subscribe to desired topics. When an event happens related to a topic, our server will send notification message to all subscribed clients of the topic.
It seems that STOMP is very appliable to our case. So Spring Websocket is already used.

But there was a problem that our client isn't STOMP. So we extend `TextWebSocketHandler` and in it's `afterConnectionEstablished` method, create a new `WebSocketStompClient` and bind it to the websocket session, for each clients. Then we convert any received messages from STOMP session and send it to the corresponding websocket session. They are implemented in `handleTextMessage` method. Indeed, we are connecting a STOMP connection to ourself in the server-side to simulate STOMP client. We have to do so just because our client isn't STOMP.

Our code is like this:

```
@Component
class MyWebSocketHandler : TextWebSocketHandler() {
    private val sessions = mutableMapOf<String, WebSocketSession>()

    override fun afterConnectionEstablished(session: WebSocketSession) {
        val webSocketStompClient = createWebSocketStompClient()

        val stompSession =
            webSocketStompClient.connect(
                "ws://$host:$port/stomp",
                /* some headers and a StompSessionHandler */
            ).get()

        sessions[session.principal] =
            ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator(session, 20_000, 10_000_000).also {
                it.attributes["STOMP_SESSION"] = stompSession
            }
    }

    override fun handleTextMessage(session0: WebSocketSession, message: TextMessage) {
        if (isSubscribeMessage(message.payload)) {
            val stompSession = findStompSessionByWebSocketSessionId(session.id)
            val topicId = extractTopicIdSubscribeMessage(message.payload)
            val subscription = stompSession.subscribe(
                "/topic/${topicId}",
                object : StompFrameHandler {
                    override fun getPayloadType(headers: StompHeaders): Type = String::class.java

                    override fun handleFrame(headers: StompHeaders, payload: Any?) =
                        session.sendMessage(TextMessage(payload as String))
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then we simply use `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend` to send notifications in our event handler.

```
class MyEventHandler(
    private val topic: String,
    private val simpMessagingTemplate: SimpMessagingTemplate
) {

   fun handle(event: Event) {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/${event.topic}", "Some notification message")
    }
}
```

Now I have the following questions:

1. First of all, I think that our approach is not good. Am I right? Is there any better way to benefit Spring Websocket without STOMP client?
2. Another problem is we use default spring in-memory broker rather than RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ. What are it's pros and cons? In my opinion, using in-memory broker is better in context of performance because there is no network call. But the huge number of concurrent clients may cuase some resource issues.
3. I am asked to make the application reactive and adapt with Spring Webflux. How should I do so such that still benefit STOMP? I am new to reactive programming and AFAIK there is no support for STOMP. I think that there is an architectural gap between reactive programming and STOMP protocol that I cannot understand.

Any advice would be much appreciated!